# Latex Page Width Increase

Tags: tables, width, page

I am currently working on a paper using the IEEE Access template in LaTeX. I have a wide table that exceeds the default page width (I have used * to make the table full-size), and I would like to extend the page width for that particular table only. Is there a way to achieve this in LaTeX? I want to ensure that the rest of the document remains formatted according to the IEEE Access guidelines while allowing for a wider page specifically for this table.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to modify the page width for a single table within the IEEE Access template would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Put your table in a `\makebox` with zero width, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707103/101651).

Comment: I want to extend the default page size for that particular table, but it is also not working with makebox.

Comment: Add a minimal example in your post, then. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: The image does not help us to help you, please add a minimal example of your code.

Comment: technically it is easy to change the page dimensions but if this is for a IEEE journal they probably would refuse to publish it if you do. The whole point of publisher journal classes is to remove such choices from the author. Especially if it's a printed journal they choose the page size, they may be more flexible with online publications.

Comment: Have you tried placing the table in landscape mode on a page by itself?

Comment: @Mico, I did and solved it that way. Thanks a ton.